# Getting referringParams of onInitFinished null unless kill the app for first time

Tags: android, branch.io

I am using branch in android app for deep linking, `referringParams` of `onInitFinished` are coming as `null`.

If I kill the app on first run, it works fine after first time kill.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there is an issue with the setup of the Branch SDK. I suggest checking the integration against the one mentioned in the documentation: https://docs.branch.io. Make sure that all the lifecycle events are hit when the app launches with the use of breakpoints.

If you are still facing issues, feel free to write to integrations@branch.io and we will be happy to assist you.